# Connecting grails to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, grails, intellij-idea

I am using Grails with IntelliJ studio. How can I set my application.yml file in order to connect to my postgres version 9.5.3 ?

Answer (score 2):

First to create the database, use something similar to this sql:

```
CREATE USER my_user WITH PASSWORD 'my_secret_password'; 
CREATE DATABASE my_db; 
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE my_db TO my_user;
```

Test the db connection with:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U my_user my_db -W
```

Then use something like this in your application.yml file:

```
environments:
    production:
        dataSource:
            driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
            dbCreate: update
            username: my_user
            password: my_secret_password
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
            url: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/my_db
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Assuming your Postgres is running on localhost and standard port 5432. 
Since the strategy is update, this will create all tables in the database for you. After that, you might wish to change update to validate, and use database migrations for your changes to the domain classes.

You probably wish to update the username, password and database name

Finally in the build.gradle file, you need to include the driver as a runtime dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
    ...
}
```

Comment: do I need to change something in the build file too?

Comment: and should I log in via pgadmin for example and create myDbname database?if yes should I create any table?

Comment: I've updated the answer with info on the build file and how to create the database.